# How to use OAuth without opening identity provider's login form and use mine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wpf, oauth-2.0

I need to authenticate the user using OAuth 2.0 protocol.
As I read that a main step in the process is to open a popup window for the user contains the login form of the identity provider and then redirect to a page with the access token.
I have a case where I need to use my login form and want the user to enter his\her credentials in it.

I'm using Azure AD as identity provider, but the question is in general.

Maybe you think in this way we missed the whole point of OAuth, but I was wondering if this is possible, because I want to use it with WPF application and ASP.NET MVC too, so in WPF it's not suitable to open browser window to let the user enter their credentials.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, OAuth 2.0 does not support user authentication, see: http://oauth.net/articles/authentication/. User authentication based on OAuth 2.0 can only be done with an extension of OAuth 2.0 and some providers (e.g. Facebook) have built their own extension for this purpose. The standardized extension of OAuth 2.0 for authentication of users is called OpenID Connect http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html.

As to your question: entering user credentials in to a client application is exactly the anti-pattern that OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect are trying to prevent. Yet there is a "migration" flow for OAuth 2.0 called the Resource Owner Password Credentials flow that could be used in this way, though the spec emphasizes that it is only for migration purposes and is not preferred, see: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.7.

You may be able to find a provider that supports this flow but realistically speaking no provider should (when following the spec). As an example, Google doesn't support Resource Owner Password Credentials flow because they don't want Google credentials to be leaked to 3rd party sites.